# Error on using pagination with subquery in @query annotation JPA

Tags: spring-boot, pagination, spring-data-jpa, subquery, jpql

PriceListDurationRepository

```
package com.Pricing.Pricing_App.repository;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model.PriceListDetail;
import com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model.PriceListDuration;
import java.util.List;      
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

@Repository
public interface PriceListDurationRepository extends CrudRepository<PriceListDuration, String> {

    String mQuery = "SELECT qplt, qplab"    
                     + " ,(SELECT iuomt1.unitOfMeasure FROM UnitsOfMeasureTransTbl iuomt1) "
                 + " FROM PriceListDuration qplab, PriceListDetail qplt " 
                 + " WHERE qplab.priceListId           =qplt.priceListId ";

    @Query(value = mQuery + " AND esib.itemNumber = :itemnumber")
    Page<PriceListDuration> getByItemNumber(String itemnumber, Pageable pageable);
}
```

I am using pagination in the getByItemNumber method.
But it returns error because of the subquery at the column level.

Error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'priceListDurationController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'priceListDurationRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'priceListDurationRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Count query validation failed for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.Pricing.Pricing_App.repository.PriceListDurationRepository.getByItemNumber(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:572) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.Pricing.Pricing_App.PricingAppApplication.main(PricingAppApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'priceListDurationRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Count query validation failed for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.Pricing.Pricing_App.repository.PriceListDurationRepository.getByItemNumber(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Count query validation failed for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.Pricing.Pricing_App.repository.PriceListDurationRepository.getByItemNumber(java.lang.String,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:565) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:558) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:560) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:550) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:550) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:323) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$4(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting EOF, found ')' near line 1, column 258 [select count(iuomb1) FROM com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model.UnitsOfMeasure iuomb1, com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model.UnitsOfMeasureTransTbl iuomt1 WHERE iuomb1.uomCode=qpli.pricingUOMCode AND iuomt1.unitOfMeasureId =iuomb1.unitOfMeasureId AND iuomt1.language  ='US')  FROM com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model.PriceListDuration qplab, com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model.PriceListDetail qplt, com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model.PriceListItem qpli, com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model.ItemDetail esib, com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model.PriceListCharge qplc  WHERE qplab.priceListId           =qplt.priceListId  AND qpli.priceListId            = qplab.priceListId  AND esib.inventoryItemId        =qpli.itemId  AND qpli.priceListId            =qplc.priceListId  AND qplc.parentEntityId         =qpli.priceListItemId  AND qplt.language               ='US'  AND qplab.orgId                 =300001096431127  AND qplab.statusCode            = 'APPROVED'  AND esib.organizationId         =300000245868293  AND qplc.parentEntityTypeCode='PRICE_LIST_ITEM'  AND sysdate BETWEEN NVL(qplc.startDate,sysdate) AND NVL(qplc.endDate,sysdate)  AND sysdate BETWEEN NVL(qplab.startDate,sysdate) AND NVL(qplab.endDate,sysdate)  AND esib.itemNumber = :itemnumber]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:670) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy84.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    ... 58 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting EOF, found ')' near line 1, column 258 [select count(iuomb1) FROM com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model.UnitsOfMeasure iuomb1, com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model.UnitsOfMeasureTransTbl iuomt1 WHERE iuomb1.uomCode=qpli.pricingUOMCode AND iuomt1.unitOfMeasureId =iuomb1.unitOfMeasureId AND iuomt1.language  ='US')  FROM com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model.PriceListDuration qplab, com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model.PriceListDetail qplt, com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model.PriceListItem qpli, com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model.ItemDetail esib, com.Pricing.Pricing_App.model.PriceListCharge qplc  WHERE qplab.priceListId           =qplt.priceListId  AND qpli.priceListId            = qplab.priceListId  AND esib.inventoryItemId        =qpli.itemId  AND qpli.priceListId            =qplc.priceListId  AND qplc.parentEntityId         =qpli.priceListItemId  AND qplt.language               ='US'  AND qplab.orgId                 =300001096431127  AND qplab.statusCode            = 'APPROVED'  AND esib.organizationId         =300000245868293  AND qplc.parentEntityTypeCode='PRICE_LIST_ITEM'  AND sysdate BETWEEN NVL(qplc.startDate,sysdate) AND NVL(qplc.endDate,sysdate)  AND sysdate BETWEEN NVL(qplab.startDate,sysdate) AND NVL(qplab.endDate,sysdate)  AND esib.itemNumber = :itemnumber]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:291) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:186) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
```

If I remove the

```
Page<PriceListDuration> getByItemNumber(String itemnumber, Pageable pageable)
```

with `List<PriceListDuration> getByItemNumber(String itemnumber)`; then it works.
Seems pagination does not support subquery.
Is there any alternate way to use pagination to this method ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I faced with such problem. Custom query and Pageable didn't work well. So I implement pagination using limit and offset in custom query. Maybe it will help you:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM practicemanager.practices WHERE student_id = ?1 LIMIT ?2 OFFSET ?3",
        nativeQuery = true)
List<PracticesEntity> findByStudentIdLimit(int studentId, int limit, int offset);
```